# MaxLength - Data annotation EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am iterating over some JSON to get data in an EF Core database. All is good.

I am looking at using data annotations to get it to show all the rows which exceed a `MaxLength`.

So I putting this in my `DbContext`:

```
[MaxLength(6,ErrorMessage = "This is rubbish it does not work")]
```

Then I see on the Microsoft website

[image]

So how can I check the length of a column before submission, so I can create a `<List>` of all rows which exceed the `MaxLength` ?

Comment: If you apply a schema change to an existing database you can choose between allowing data loss and not allowing it. If you allow it, you'll possibly loose data.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to check each column, if there is any content with length > maxlength. For this, you can use the `LEN(column)` function of SQL.

Comment: Is there an override function for me to get the data from ??